# How to get standard notation (rather than scientific) when hovering over pie chart in Plotly

Tags: python, pandas, plotly

I have a pie chart that displays worldwide movie sales by rating. When I hover over the chart the woldwide sales are being displayed in scientific notation. How do I fix this so that worldwide sales are represented in standard notation instead? I would appreciate it if anyone has a solution to this in express or graph objects (or both).
Thank you.

```
# formatting and importing data
import pandas as pd

movie_dataframe =  pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NicholasTuttle/public_datasets/main/movie_data.csv")   # importing dataset to dataframe

movie_dataframe['worldwide_gross'] = movie_dataframe['worldwide_gross'].str.replace(',', '', regex=True)          # removing commas from column
movie_dataframe['worldwide_gross'] = movie_dataframe['worldwide_gross'].str.replace('$', '' , regex=True )        # removing dollar signs from column
movie_dataframe['worldwide_gross'] = movie_dataframe['worldwide_gross'].astype(float)

# narrowing dataframe to specific columns
movies_df = movie_dataframe.loc[:, ['title', 'worldwide_gross', 'rating', 'rt_score', 'rt_freshness']]
```

```
# plotly express
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.pie(movies_df,
             values= movies_df['worldwide_gross'],
             names= movies_df['rating'],             
             )

fig.show()
```

```
# plotly graph objects
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Pie(
    values = movies_df['worldwide_gross'],
    labels = movies_df['rating']
))

fig.show()
```

Comment: Perhaps you could read this page from the docs: https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look here: https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#disabling-or-customizing-hover-of-columns-in-plotly-express

Basically you give a dictionary of row name and format string to `hover_data`. The formatting string follows the d3-format's syntax.

```py
import plotly.express as px

fig = px.pie(
    movies_df, values= movies_df['worldwide_gross'], names= movies_df['rating'], 
    hover_data={
        "worldwide_gross": ':.d',
        # "worldwide_gross": ':.2f', # float
    }
)

fig.show()
```

For the graph object API you need to write an `hover_template`:
https://plotly.com/python/reference/pie/#pie-hovertemplate

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure(go.Pie(
    values = movies_df['worldwide_gross'],
    labels = movies_df['rating'],
    hovertemplate='Rating: %{label}<br />World wide gross: %{value:d}<extra></extra>'
))

fig.show()
```